# How to get random unread article?

Tags: sql, database, random, backendless

Database table `articles` contains 10.000 rows (articles)
I want to get a random article, mark it as read and never get it again,
so my next get request should return random article except that one.
There are thousands of users like me and all of them are using this table.

How do I implement this? How do I mark those articles, and how do I search only unread articles?

I was trying to create the column `relatedUsers` in the `Articles` table, which is filled out with relations to user objects, who has read the article. I was using search query: `relatedUsers.objectId!=currentUserId` But when this column get 2+ relatedUsers, this solutions stops working, because the database returns articles, which has at least one relatedUser, who's objectId isn't equal to `currentUserId` (means all users).

I'm using Backendless.com right now, but if I guess, the solution should be applicable to any database, including backendless. If not, then what kind of database should I use for this?

Comment: There are no info about sql server. Microsoft SQL Server ? MySql ?
give the full current querry please, not only "relatedUsers.objectId!=currentUserId"

Comment: You need another table, called something like `UserArticles` that has one row per user and per read article.

Comment: Andrey Rybalkin, if you know how to solve this with some particular databse - use it in your answer, i'm open to switch to anyone.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, i don't get it, how will this table help me?

Comment: @stkvtflw . . . You might want to solve this with a "real" database . . . like Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, and so on.

Comment: Do you need a unique article for one user or unique article for all users? I mean, after one of the users get the article, can the other ones still get it too     or it also becomes unavailable for them?

Comment: Also, which SDK do you use?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do now is:

1. Create a table named `UserArticle` with fields `articleId` and `userId`
2. When you add a user or an article, you should also add to this table relations to all articles or users respectively; this way your `UserArticle` table will contain the relations between articles and users who haven't yet read those articles
3. And in order to get a random not read article for user, you:

   1. Retrieve items from `UserArticle` where `userId = yourCurrentUserId`
   2. Randomly select one of them and retrieve an article by its ID
   3. Remove the selected article from `UserArticle` by `articleId` and `userId`, meaning that the user has read the article

This approach is the most suitable in your case. It involves a little more than one request, but for now your requirements cannot be fit better.

Also we (the Backendless team) are working on a keyword like `contains`, using which you would be able to have only a relation to Users table and get not read articles in one request, so the suggested approach is pretty temporary.

Comment: For the step 3.1 you could add some "randomness" by assigning a random offset when you retrieve a collection of objects.

Comment: ..but note that if your offset happens to be bigger than the size of the found collection, you'll get an empty collection

Answer (score 1):

Getting a random number depends on the database.  But the basic idea is to have a table called `UserArticles` with one row per user and per article already read (and perhaps other information such as the time).

Then, you can do:

```
select a.*
from articles a
where not exists (select 1
                  from userarticles ua
                  where a.article_id = ua.article_id and ua.user_id = $user_id
                 ) 
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

The `order by rand() limit 1` is definitely database-dependent.  But, it gives you the idea of how to approach the problem.

Once you have selected the article, then you insert this information into `UserArticles`:

```
insert into UserArticles(user_id, article_id)
    values ($user_id, $article_id);
```

where `$article_id` refers to the article retrieved in the previous step.

Note:  this should be fine with respect to race conditions, unless a single user can have multiple simultaneous connections to the database asking for the same information.  Handling that case requires more knowledge about the database being used.

Comment: He uses Backendless.com. There are specific limited lang. It is not sql database

Comment: Actually, it is sql database and one can use SQL-like where-clause: https://backendless.com/documentation/data/rest/data_search_and_query.htm